# Android Studio Recyclerview use Retrofit

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-recyclerview, retrofit

please help me..
i have 10 policy data on my PHP to show on recyclerview android studio using retrofit..but, when i run my emulator, the emulator just show 1 data..my plan just show PolicyNo..when i running emulator and check my log, they've said : my Number Policy Received: 10

sorry for my bad english :(

[image: result from emulator]

here is my policyActivity :

```
 public class PolicyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = PolicyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String policyno;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_policy);



        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.policy_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        ApiEndPoint apiEndPoint =
                ApiClient.getClient(this).create(ApiEndPoint.class);

        Call<PolicyStatus> call = apiEndPoint.getPolicyNo(policyno);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PolicyStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PolicyStatus> call, Response<PolicyStatus> response) {
                List<PolicyNo> policyNo = response.body().getPolicyNo();
                Log.d(TAG, "Number Policy Received: " + policyNo.size());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new PolicyAdapter(policyNo, R.layout.list_item_policy, getApplicationContext()));

            }


                @Override
                public void onFailure (Call <PolicyStatus> call, Throwable t){
                    Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is my policyadapter:

```
 public class PolicyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PolicyAdapter.PolicyViewHolder> {


    private List<PolicyNo> policyNo;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class PolicyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout policyLayout;
        TextView nomorpolis;

        public PolicyViewHolder (View v){
            super(v);
            policyLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.policy_layout);
            nomorpolis = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nomorpolis);
        }
    }
    public PolicyAdapter (List<PolicyNo>policyNo, int rowLayout, Context context){
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
        this.context = context;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public PolicyAdapter.PolicyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new PolicyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (PolicyViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.nomorpolis.setText(policyNo.get(position).getPolicyNo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return policyNo.size();}

}
```

PolicyStatus :

```
 public class PolicyStatus {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("PolicyNo")
    @Expose
    private List<PolicyNo> policyNo = null;

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<PolicyNo> getPolicyNo() {
        return policyNo;
    }

    public void setPolicyNo(List<PolicyNo> policyNo) {
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
    }
```

PolicyNo :

```
 public class PolicyNo {

    @SerializedName("ANO")
    @Expose
    private Integer aNO;
    @SerializedName("PolicyNo")
    @Expose
    private String policyNo;
    @SerializedName("ADate")
    @Expose
    private ADate aDate;
    @SerializedName("ADATE")
    @Expose
    private String aDATE;

    public Integer getANO() {
        return aNO;
    }

    public void setANO(Integer aNO) {
        this.aNO = aNO;
    }

    public String getPolicyNo() {
        return policyNo;
    }

    public void setPolicyNo(String policyNo) {
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
    }

    public ADate getADate() {
        return aDate;
    }

    public void setADate(ADate aDate) {
        this.aDate = aDate;
    }

    public String getADATE() {
        return aDATE;
    }

    public void setADATE(String aDATE) {
        this.aDATE = aDATE;
    }

    public PolicyNo (String policyNo){
        this.policyNo = policyNo;

    }

}
```

api endpoint :

```
 @GET ("policy.php")
Call<PolicyStatus> getPolicyNo (@Query("PolicyNo") String policyNo);
```

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Can you post list_item_policy.xml ?

Comment: <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/policy_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomorpolis"
        android:text="@string/nomorpolis"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have given `list_item_policy` to `match_parent`. as you are saying you are getting 10 size in log. then this can be only reason. may be you will find items on scroll. **So just change this to `wrap_content`**.

Also check your `recyclerView` getting full height check in the preview.

Comment: omg.when i scroll, i found my data.so,how i set my list_item_policy?
here is my list_item_policy :

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/policy_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomorpolis"
        android:text="@string/nomorpolis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: for list_item_policy.xml :
https://pastebin.com/iWGUSJ2E

for activity_policy.xml :
https://pastebin.com/y7EwPx1q

Comment: list_item_policy : https://pastebin.com/zyJpHuNr activity_policy: https://pastebin.com/jLwP9jPx

Comment: ooo yeaah..its worked!!!...thank u very muccccccchhhh.....u'r awesome !!!!

Comment: @MathewsEdward Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Comment: hi, @Vishva Dave, can u help me again?
i have difficult situation, i'm gonna search my data policy yesterday by filter using date range picker..can u help me?or show me tutorial from another link to my guidance?

Comment: @MathewsEdward you will need one web service for this. this will be by server side. we just pass the dates as parameters and response will be accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine except one thing which I noticed :-

Do this :-

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

instead of :-

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```